# django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name postgresql-db to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

запустил сайт на облачном сервере Ubuntu. сайт работает, через админку данные добавляются в postgresql и отображаются на сайте. Есть скрипт вне проекта Django парсит сайти и заносит в postgresql информацию(на локальной машине все работает проверено)призапуске выдает ошибку django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name postgresql-db to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой подскажите как исправить?

settings.py

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': locals_vars.PG_NAME,
        'USER': locals_vars.PG_USER,
        'PASSWORD': locals_vars.PG_PASSWORD, # as a POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        'HOST': locals_vars.PG_HOST, # as the DB's service name in docker-compose.yml
        'PORT': '', # default
    }
}
```

.pg-env

```
POSTGRES_USER=deploy-test-user
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=deploy-test-password
POSTGRES_DB=deploy-db
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: "3.9"

services:
  nginx:
    restart: always
    build:
        context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80" # port exposed to outside world.
      
  django-backend:
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ./django-backend
    image: djangobackend

  postgresql-db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    env_file:
      - ./postgresql-db/.pg-env # why - see the next step
```

Answer (score 0):

решилось, добавил строку volumes в docker-compose.yml

```
postgresql-db:
    restart: always
    image: postgres
    volumes: 
     - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - ./postgresql-db/.pg-env # why - see the next step
```